# autoexec.bat equivalent for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to do things like:

- set up my configuration for vi
- set up my prompt display string

etc

At the moment, I am having to do that everytime I log on, is there a way to 'automate' this, so I don't have to do it manually each time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

autoexec.bat is kind of a launch-mechanism instead of a configure-my-tools-again-and-again-mechanism. you would not setup your notepad-config via autoexec.bat either, so your the right config files for the tools:

- vi / vim uses `.vimrc` (and `.gvimrc`) for its settings
- the prompt for your shell (bash, zsh etc) is configured by:

  - `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` for bash
  - `.zshrc` for zsh
  - `.tcshrc` for tcsh etc.

provide use with more information about what you are using and we could help more.